# Django and Jbrowse

Tags: django, jbrowse

Did you tried to integrate jBrowse (https://jbrowse.org/) into a django web application? if so, can you please describe how you did it? thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to put the jbrowse folder like it is in the static directory of your webapp and after call it as follows:

`<iframe style="border: 1px solid #505050;" src="/static/jbrowse/index.html" height="600" width="1000"></iframe>`

hope it helps others